# What other functions have these properties besides the product?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am looking for functions of two variables, $f(x,y)$, defined on the positive quadrant $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$, with the following properties:

1. Continuous;
2. Non-negative: $f(x,y)\geq 0$;
3. Symmetric: $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$;
4. If $f(x,y)>0$ then $x>0$ and $y>0$;
5. Monotonic: if $x>0$ and $y_2>y_1$, then $f(x,y_2)>f(x,y_1)$; similarly, if $y>0$ and $x_2>x_1$, then $f(x_2,y)>f(x_1,y)$.

All these properties are satisfied by the product function $f(x,y)=x\cdot y$, as well as by any monotone transformation of it ($f(x,y)=g(x\cdot y)$ for any continuous increasing function $g$ with $g(0)=0$).
What other functions have these properties?

Comment: Take $f(x,y)=(xy)^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: For any symmetric positive measurable function $g(u,v)$ of two variables, the function $f(x,y) = \int_0^x \int_0^y g(u,v)\,dv\,du$ satisfies these properties.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Indeed. The same is true for any monotonic transformation of $xy$ - any $g(xy)$ such that $g$ is continuous, increasing, and has $g(0)=0$.

Comment: @Magma Interesting! Is the product a special case of this, for some $g$?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: Yes, for $g(u, v) = 1$.

Comment: @Magma ... More generally than a Radon-Nikodym differentiable function $f(x,y) = \iint g(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ in $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$, you could use another measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$, locally finite, continuous, support = $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$, symmetric for the reflection $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.  Then take $f(x,y) = \mu\big([0,x]\times[0,y]\big)$.